# getDescribe in standard Activity object returns a Null Pointer

Tags: apex, schema

I have the following statement for trying to getdescribe for the standard activity object

```
Schema.SObjectType s = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Activity') ;
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe() ;
```

this returns a null pointer , which makes no sense, as I can do that same statement for custom and standard objects alike, only Activity has given me so far this null pointer

any ideas? I have tried lowercase, came error

Answer (score 2):

Activity is a fake object that represents task and event/calendar which are the real objects.
Talked about a little here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008nmTIAQ

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities.htm&type=5