# How to retrieve exactly all SObject Names in Object Manager

Tags: sobject, object

On the Object Manager tab, My org has 173 objects with 172 standard objects and 1 custom object. However, when I use `System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values().size());` It returns 1058 records. Is there any way to only retrieve only 173 objects' information displayed on the UI? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering using the IsCustomizable property. This property is true if custom fields can be defined for the entity, which is the case for the objects shown in the object manager.

```
SELECT Label, QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable = true
```

Also, the following is the best I think you will achieve to cover Custom vs Standard.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Set<String> standardObjects = new Set<String>();
Set<String> customObjects = new Set<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectType d : gd.values()){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ds = d.getDescribe();
    if(!ds.isCreateable())
      continue;
    if(ds.isCustom() == false && ds.getRecordTypeInfos().size() > 0)
        standardObjects.add(ds.getName());
    else if(ds.isCustom())
        customObjects.add(ds.getName());
}

List<String> sortedNames = new List<String>(customObjects);
sortedNames.sort();
for(String name : sortedNames)
  System.debug('Custom object: ' + name);
sortedNames = new List<String>(standardObjects);
sortedNames.sort();
for(String name : sortedNames)
  System.debug('Standard object: ' + name);
```

Comment: Hi @Tushar Jadav I notice that the `getGlobalDescribe()` method cannot return Activity, Waitlist, Waitlist Participant, Waitlist Service Resource, Waitlist Work Type Objects. Is there any special logic in these objects? And how can I retrieve these object infomation?

Comment: @TuấnTrầnquốc, Refer to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399545/getdescribe-in-standard-activity-object-returns-a-null-pointer

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Tushar Jadav, I tried both solutions but still can not retrieve the expected output. For the second method, it's mismatch many objects. For example: It Cannot query: ApiAnomalyEventStore, AssetAction, AssetActionSource, etc But query some redundant objects like: Announcement, AppAnalyticsQueryRequest, AppointmentScheduleAggr, CalendarView, etc